# How do i transfer my world save from minecraft ps3 edition to minecraft for windows 10 (Bedrock edition)?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that Xbox one edition worlds can be transferred from Xbox one edition to the bedrock version of Minecraft on Xbox one. so I'm guessing that ps3 edition worlds 'should' be able to transfer to windows 10 edition since ps3 edition is basically the same as Xbox one edition and Minecraft bedrock for Xbox one is basically the same as the windows 10 edition. if it is possible to do what I asked can you please comment because I would appreciate it. also I've already researched and cant find anything on other websites. I'm just saying because I've previously had a down voted question because someone thought I had a lack of research.

Comment: There’s a difference. Xbox One Edition and Bedrock Edition are actually two separate things. Hopefully, soon, PS3 → PS4 → future PS4 Bedrock Edition?

Comment: I know that they are different but I thought that since Xbox one edition can be transferred to bedrock on Xbox than it SHOULD be possible to transfer from ps3 to windows 10.

Comment: Good point. Technically, PS3 would be more like Xbox 360, but I see the logic, because PS3 can be converted to PS4, and Xbox 360 to Xbox One

Answer (score 1):

To move your PS3 saves to Bedrock you must use PS4 Edition (via going to editions in the updated bedrock edition of it) to get your save file up to the PS4 Edition, go back to its updated Bedrock edition of it in order to bring that PS4 (from PS3) save to Bedrock edition.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I actually new that bedrock not existing on ps4 at the time I asked this stopped me from being able to do this without a special tool back when I made the question. I also don't have a ps4, that's another issue. I can maybe ask my cousin if I can borrow his ps4 so I can get the worlds onto my pc.

Comment: also, you can't have a world between platforms rn w/o using a realm for that world (on PS4) and copying it on your Windows 10 version of Bedrock.

Answer (score -1):

Mcc tool chest here is a direct download link: http://www.mcctoolchest.com/Download/file/MCCToolChest_Setup just save the file and open the world  from minecarft console edition and click tools and convert there you go

Comment: This doesn't seem to be well documented. Are you affiliated with the developer of this tool? Have you used it before?